# Is this thread safe?

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, runnable

I am writing an application for Android and am using worker threads to process certain information. Having read through my code I am now unsure if it is thread safe.

I have written a simplified version of my code, I have omitted the `Handler` object used to communicate with the main thread and obviously the process itself.

```
public class myClass implements Runnable
{
    private String myString;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        myString = "Some Value";
    }
}
```

This is called by running something similar to this.

```
myClass class = new myClass();
Thread thread = new Thread(class);
thread.start()
```

So, is this code not thread safe because I am modifying `myString` (declared in the main thread) in the `run()` function?

Comment: Your question reminds me a lot of this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In itself, that's thread-safe. But which threads are going to be *reading* the `myString` value? If you read it from the main thread after writing it in the new thread, that *isn't* thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

No, as you have presented it, it is thread safe. If you make a getter for the myString variable, you have a potential threading issue. In that case you would want to make the getter/setter method synchronized, or better yet make the variable volatile, which will ensure that the variable's value is the same for every thread.